# Bash how to feed multiple command line arguments to Xgraph

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

Using the Xgraph data plotting tool ([XGRAPH](https://www.xgraph.org/#anch2.7)), I want to plot a bunch of files named test1.csv
test2.csv,
...

The command would be

```
xgraph -columns 1 2 test1.csv -columns 1 2 test2.csv
```

and so on·
Is there any way I can use brace expansion or some other magic to circumvent manually typing the pattern `-columns 1 2 file.csv`  again and again?

Comment: `my_function(){ for f ; do xgraph -columns 1 2 "$f"; done; }; my_function test{1..100}.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this function should work for you...

```
graph-build() {
  # loop through commandline filenames and join together
  for file in "${@}"; do
    cmd_build+=(-columns 1 2 "${file}")
  done
  # run xgraph
  xgraph "${cmd_build[@]}"
}

# Run with the expansion as required.
graph-build file{1..3}.csv
```

Edit:
Syntax updated due to helpful comments highlighting the whitespace issue with filenames in my initial revisions.

Comment: use bash arrays to build arguments

Comment: You could use an array, but I have to ask, what is wrong with the method I chose?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 That for exmaple files with spaces will not work. Check your scripts with shellcheck

Comment: Thanks, I will amend. I found another source explaining as well. I still have to shake off old habits :)

Comment: Thank you, it works well! Just one typo "-column" should be  "-columns" for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

With the specific set of filenames given in the question you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) and [eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-eval) to replace

```
xgraph -columns 1 2 test1.csv -columns 1 2 test2.csv ... -columns 1 2 test10.csv
```

with

```
eval xgraph ' -columns 1 2 test'{1..10}'.csv'
```

- `eval` is dangerous in general, and is best avoided.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).  It's safe in this case, because there are no variable expansions involved in the expression.